# Given a set of points, describe the structure(number of holes, etc.)

Tags: general-topology

If we stay in two dimentions, we may consider graphs.
Suppose we have a set of points

abc  bcd ak kd (a generic example)

How may one go about counting the holes in the structure, and it's general "shape"

I am new to the field and these kind of questions, so I would be very grateful for any links and pointers, as to what to read.

Comment: If you are given a concrete planar graph, an easy way to calculate the genus ("number of holes") is just to draw the picture and count how many regions it divides the plane into, not counting the exterior region.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there an algebraic method? Meaning, without drawing?

Comment: Yes, see http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Topology_of_graphs#Holes_vs_cycles.

Comment: Very nice, thank you, I will study the entire article.
Might I bother you and as, for a few more links, or phrases i might google, to get a grasp at the basics of the subject. I am an amateur who studies on his own, using pointers from kind strangers.

Comment: The important terms for your question are the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29) and/or [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic). In general this is the realm of [topological graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_graph_theory).